# How to quickly reopen ediff with the same files

Tags: ediff

I ran `ediff` on file A and B, and then quit it to do a git commit. Then I want to reopen ediff (let's call it `rediff`) with the same pair of files.
How do I do this? There is the `eregistry` thing that I thought it is for this purpose.But I couldn't make it work. When I type `z` and quit `ediff`, there is nothing in the `eregistry` when I do `M-x eregistry`.

Comment: If A and B files are in split windows, I can suggest a generic wrapper fn to quickly do ediff between them.

Comment: @KaushalModi the `z` and `M-x eregistry` are working now for me. I am not clear why they did not work before. Maybe because I was running some inferior buffers on the A and B so `ediff` could not go to sleep. All in all, I suspend looking for alternative solution for now. Some one interested in the same process can use `z` and `M-x eregistry`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a quick way to repeat *any* complex command (that is, a command that uses the minibuffer to read input): **`C-x ESC ESC`** (aka `C-x M-ESC`), `repeat-complex-command`.

That inserts the Lisp form of the last complex command you executed in the minibuffer.

You can use `M-p` or `M-r`, as usual, to retrieve previous elements from the input history.  So if the last complex command was your `ediff` command then `C-x ESC ESC` puts it in the minibuffer, and you just hit `RET` (Enter key) to repeat the command.  If the `ediff` command was further back than the last command then just use `M-p`... or `M-r` to retrieve it.